# NextJS 13 + Tailwind grid-cols and col-span not working?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have a NextJS 13 + Tailwind project. There is a component rendered N times with `map` function like this:

```
{cardsData.content.map((value: CardData, index: number) => (
        <motion.div
          className={selectedId === value.title ? openCardStyles : `${cardStyles} ${value.classNames}`}
          key={index}
        >
...rest of code
```

I want to concatenate `cardStyles` and `${value.classNames}` dynamically as shown above. The `cardsData` is passed from a JSON file:

```
"cardsData": {
    "content": [
      {
        "classNames": "text-5xl grid-cols-1 col-span-2",
      ....rest of data
```

The problem is, all other Tailwind classes are working but the `grid-cols-1 col-span-2`. In the DevTools, I can see the classes. All other classes are rendering CSS except `grid-cols-1 col-span-2`:
[image]
As you can see, `text-5xl` works fine, but not `grid-cols-1 col-span-2` even if they are passed into the TSX as the same time.

What's strange is if I hard-code `grid-cols-1 col-span-2` in the TSX like this

```
className={selectedId === value.title ? openCardStyles : `col-span-2 ${cardStyles} ${value.classNames}`}
```

The `col-span-2` works and if I remove it, all classes including `grid-cols-1 col-span-2` works as expected. It will stop working again if I restart the NextJS server.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to also add the `grid` class, when using `grid-cols-{n}` and `col-span-{n}`
- Another thing worth mentioning, is that TailwindCSS generates CSS based on the class names it finds in your porject at *build* time, therefore any class names added at runtime will not do anything, as those classes are not defined in the generated css. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names. If these class names exist in your project at build time, than make sure to configure tailwind to scan the files in which they are defined. E.g. if they are defined in a JSON file, the problem might be that tailwind only checks the following file extensions fro classes: `.js, .jsx, .html, .ts, .tsx` files but not `.json` files

Comment: Thanks you. The `grid` class is added in the motion.div's parent element. It's still not working. Also I'm sure Tailwind scanned JSON as the `text-5xl` class was recognised and working

Comment: Is it possible that `text-5xl` is picked up by tailwind in another part of the code base, but not `grid-cols-1` and `col-span-2`? the fact, that when you hard code them, it works, seems to point in this direction. Posting your `tailwind.config.js` might help.